# delete a symbolic link doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu

```
ll example_plugin
./
../
.buildpath
DEDBIAN/
plugin -> ../../../../example_plugin/var/www/plugin
.project
.settings/
.svn/
var/
```

I want actually to delete the symbolic link plugin.

```
sudo unlink plugin
```

and

```
sudo rm plugin
```

doesn't work for me , it gives the output

```
unlink: impossible to delete <<plugin>> opération not permitted
```

Comment: Why the `sudo`? If the link is in a directory you control, you don't need special privs to delete it. Otherwise what are your access rights on the directory that holds the link  (`example_plugin` I think)? Is that an Eclipse workspace?

Comment: i use sudo because without i don't have permission. i am working on a Phpstorm workspace. because of the the symbolic link i can't access to my var/www/plugin directory .so i should remove it